# Mongodb error after db repair command

Tags: mongodb

I was working with MongoDB using Pymongo Libraries. Suddenly MongoDB stopped. I restarted it. After a while it stopped again. So I searched and tried the following repair command:

```
mongod --dbpath f:/data/db --repair
```

The process kept running. But I stopped it using the keyboard interruption.
Now When I am trying to use start the server using my configuration, the window is getting flashed on my screen.
I do not understand what might be the problem as I could see anything in my log file.

Here are the trace log:https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/0c6538a0124112f253c7f8e70bdde15e
Kindly, let me know what I can do so that I can start and get my data again. I have GBs of data on MongoDB, and month of hardwork will be wasted if not getting started. Please let me know the solution, if any.

Comment: This should be posted on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com). StackOverflow is for programming topics.

Answer (score 0):

```
It looks from error file
```

Detected unclean shutdown - f:\data\db\mongod.lock is not empty.
That means there are possibilities of mongod.lock corrupted or something wrong due to incorrect shutdown

Please follow the below steps
sudo rm /mongod.lock //unix command or one can follow del command in //windows to remove the mongod.lock
mongod --repair  //Now can give repair command
sudo service mongodb start //Then give start command
or
sudo service mongodb restart

In Ubuntu environment, it may required to kill process id. One can follow below steps

1. **kill current mongod process**

Find mongo processes

ps -ef | grep mongo

you'll get mongod PID

mongodb   PID     1  0 06:26 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf

2. **Stop current mongod process**

kill -9 PID

3.**start mongoDB service**

service mongodb start

Surely any of two methods would help to resolve the issue.

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: After running your command my mongo server started but mongo shell isn't why? Do I need to do something in extra. Please suggest

Comment: sudo mongod --smallfiles  //Hope this must have been run in one terminal. //Generally can follow this. Then in another terminal please give sudo mongo. In 1st terminal one can observe, connectiions : 1. If still problem exists, check mongodb.log file